# Generate expiry date in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to generate a list of medicine those are going to be expired in next three month. In the database, I have stored expiry date in the format of MM YYYY.
I'm new to PHP, can somebody help me with idea how to achieve this goal

**Php code**

```
$NintyDays = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+90 days')); 
$dbDate = '2018-12-20';
 if (strtotime($dbDate) <= strtotime($NintyDays ))
 {
 // some other code 
}
```

Comment: Give sample data And show us what you have tried so far

Comment: $NintyDays = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+90 days'));
$dbDate = '2018-12-20';

if (strtotime($dbDate) <= strtotime($NintyDays )) {
    // some other code
}

Comment: Put this in the question.

Comment: So what is the issue? Is your `PHP` code not working? Or you need `sql ` solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by sql query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM medicine_table m WHERE m.expiry < (NOW() + INTERVAL 3 MONTH)");
```

Answer (score 0):

I also advise MySQL solution as above if it can be used.

if you need PHP solution it could be like this:

```
$expDate = new DateTime('2018-12-20');
$threeMonths = new DateTime();
$threeMonths->add(new DateInterval('P3M'));

if ($expDate < $threeMonths) {
   // code
}
```